# How can I restrict WPF program to only run on Windows 8 and greater

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio, compatibility

I have a WPF program that uses the `Microsoft.Kinect` library. The Kinect V2 is only compatible with windows 8 and greater.

I was wondering if there was a built in way to have windows display an error when you try to open the program in Windows 7, XP, etc.

Currently the program instantly crashes on < Windows 8. I know I could write a custom method that grabs the version from `Environment.OSVersion` and checks to see if the major and minor versions are the same ([Microsoft Versions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion(v=vs.110).aspx)), But I would rather have something more standard.

I have tried adding a manifest to my project, and I want something like the code below, but that chooses operating systems that will be allowed to run

```xml
<application>
  <!-- A list of the Windows versions that this application has been tested on and is
       is designed to work with. Uncomment the appropriate elements and Windows will 
       automatically selected the most compatible environment. -->

  <!-- Windows Vista -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 7 -->
  <!--<supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />-->

  <!-- Windows 8 -->
  <supportedos id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

  <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />a

  <!-- Windows 10 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />

</application>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't post code as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I would get the OS version from `Environment.OSVersion` property. You may have to play around a little bit only because I am not 100% sure what Windows 8.1 RT would show, unless the Kinect library also works with RT.